# How to validate whole column in phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I am working on the phpexcel to create excel sheet and i have to validate that sheet for some columns. I tried for the below code

```
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D1')->getDataValidation();
```

It gives me cell D1 validated but i want to validate whole column D validated.So what i have to do please help

Answer (score -3):

```
foreach($j=2; $j<=10; $j++) {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("D$j")->setDataValidation(clone $objValidation);
}
```

try this [PHPExcel validate data for a range of cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818817/phpexcel-validate-data-for-a-range-of-cells)

Comment: It will validate 10 cells only what we have to do to update whole column