# How to set DataValidation of a column in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to create an Excel spreadsheet using `PHPExcel`.

I would like to *validate* a specific column. I know how to validate a cell, but I can't seem to find a method for validating a column. Can I do better than manually looping through all cells of a column?

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';<br/>

$filename='test.xlsx';<br/>
if(file_exists($filename)){<br/>
    unlink($filename);<br/>
}

$objExcel = new PHPExcel();<br/>
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objExcel);<br/>
$objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);<br/>
$objActSheet = $objExcel->getActiveSheet();<br/>
$objValidation = $objActSheet->getCell("A1")->getDataValidation(); //这一句为要设置数据有效性的单元格<br/>
$objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST)<br/>
        ->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION)<br/>
        ->setAllowBlank(false)<br/>
        ->setShowInputMessage(true)<br/>
        ->setShowErrorMessage(true)<br/>
        ->setShowDropDown(true)<br/>
        ->setErrorTitle('输入的值有误')<br/>
        ->setError('您输入的值不在下拉框列表内.')<br/>
        ->setFormula1('"列表项1,列表项2,列表项3"')<br/>
        ->setPromptTitle('设备类型');<br/>

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objExcel, 'Excel2007');<br/>

$objWriter->save('test.xlsx');<br/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do better!

For example if you want to apply validation on cells `A1:A10`, this will do the job:

```
$objActSheet->setDataValidation("A1:A10", $objValidation);
```

---

### Sources:

- [PHPExcel Github issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/325#issuecomment-298385796)
- [Relevant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46704664/6367213)

Answer (score 1):

## PhpSpreadsheet Update (after 2019)

Since PHPExcel was archived in 2019 and should not be used anymore ([see PHPExcel Repository](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)), I'll provide an update for people finding this question while using the official PHPExcel successor [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).

You'd now create a validation and then apply it to a whole cell range like that:

```php
$validation = $productSheet
    ->getCell("A1")
    ->getDataValidation()
    ->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST)
    ->setFormula1('"列表项1,列表项2,列表项3"')
    ->setAllowBlank(false)
    ->setShowDropDown(true)
    ->setShowInputMessage(true)
    ->setPromptTitle('设备类型')
    ->setShowErrorMessage(true)
    ->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION)
    ->setErrorTitle('输入的值有误')
    ->setError('您输入的值不在下拉框列表内.');

// Apply the validation to the rest of column A
$validation->setSqref('A2:A1048576');
```

[Link to the official documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell)